# Reducing DC voltage using resistor

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator

I need to supply a circuit with 12V DC from a 20V DC laptop adapter. **What is the required resistance value to be put after the laptop adapter to have a voltage drop from 20V to 12V DC?**

The adapter details are:

```
input: 100-240V, 1.5-0.8A (AC)
output: 20V, 4.5A (DC)
```

Comment: A resistor is not the way to regulate voltage, the drop across it is proportional to the current through it.

Comment: What you ask is not possible as @JohnU says. Please ask a more general question, like _how to reduce the DC voltage_. Also: what have you done yourself yet?

Comment: The issue here is that the Op doesn't realize that he's trying to reuse a laptop adapter and it's just simpler to pickup a normal DC/DC supply without using the laptop adapter as the starting point.

Comment: Why not just get a 12 V power supply?  That will be simpler and faster than rigging up something, and cheaper unless you value your time less than about $1/hour.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you know the exact current draw of the device, you cannot use a resistor to drop the voltage.

If the current draw is very, very low, you can use a potential divider to reduce voltage.

Neither are voltage regulation though. You need a voltage regulator.

A 8V drop is quite a lot and even using a linear regulator could be awkward if the current demand is high.

Comment: I realise it's possible, but that doesn't mean it should be encouraged... 8v at any sort of current is a hell of a lot of heat to dissipate!

Comment: a switching regulator should be able to handle it without much problem...

Answer (score 2):

Use 7812 chip instead with to-220 case, connect power supply + to pin 1, common ground to pin 2 and output of regulated 12 volts comes from pin 3. Use heatsink or big piece of metal to cool the component. http://www.cctvforum.com/images/imported/2011/10/169158_1.gif